# What is a good tool to graphically display module dependencies in Angular 2+?

Tags: angular, dependencies

I need to clearly display the modules we have in our project with their dependencies.

I'm working on a big scale project in Angular 7 with my team of 5+ developers. People come and go, the code review quality is not at it's best especially under time pressure. We're constantly refactoring but we've had a couple of cases where circular dependencies where discovered or where old links were not terminated.

I've tried to use this tool: https://github.com/compodoc/ngd but was met with an error `cannot enlarge memory arrays`

I expect the tool to be able to represent the modules and their links (dependencies) to other modules.